# Load Email messages attached to transaction Suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to load up all of the emails that have been sent from a transaction via SuiteScript 2.0.

When I run

```
record.getSublists()
```

it returns the following:

```
["item","activeworkflows","workflowhistory","custom8","messages","contacts","activities","usernotes","systemnotes","mediaitem","links","cases","partners","events","calls","tasks"]
```

However, when I then try to run the following:

```
record.getSublist('messages');
```

I receive an error.

I need to be able to check the date of the last email sent so I can determine whether or not to send a follow-up email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach I typically take is to use the Search API to get this type of information:

```
require(['N/search'], function(search) {
  var result = search.create({
    type: 'transaction',
    filters: [
      ['internalid', search.Operator.ANYOF, id], 'AND',
      ['mainline', search.Operator.IS, 'T'], 'AND',
      ['messages.messagetype', search.Operator.ANYOF, 'EMAIL'], 'AND',
      ['messages.isincoming', search.Operator.IS, 'F']
    ],
    columns: [
      search.createColumn({name: 'internalid', summary: search.Summary.GROUP}),
      search.createColumn({name: 'messagedate', join: 'messages', summary: search.Summary.MAX}),
    ],
  }).run().getRange({ start: 0, end: 1 });

  var dateOfLastEmail = result[0].getValue({ name: 'messagedate', join: 'messages', summary: search.Summary.MAX });
});
```

Comment: Any idea why messages comes up as a sublist but then I can't load it?

Comment: What determines whether a message is incoming or not? could you provide documentation? For example, if 2 employees email each other, will that count as an outgoing message? @michoel

Comment: @NoahHall-Potvin My guess is that any email originating from Netsuite is considered not incoming. I'm not aware of any documentation that specifically addresses this.

Comment: I have been testing, and if I attach a message to a transaction manually, with "from" of an employee, and a "to" of one of the contacts, it does not show up when I set messages.isincoming to 'F'. If I do send the email from netsuite, then it does show up. The only thing I see in the search you have created that could have any influence is the 'mainline' argument. What does this argument do?

Comment: The mainline filter is to keep only the header line of the transaction, and not any of the item lines. It's probably not needed for this search, it's a habit of mine to add it to searches where I do not want more than a single result per transaction.