# Work with sublist on record that isn't listed in record browser

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am trying to work with the list of transactions on a customer record.

When I run `record.getSublists();` the sublist shows up with id of `finhist`

However, I can not work with this sublist by calling `record.getSublist('finhist');` I'm assuming this is because the sublist is not listed in the NetSuite record browser for Customer records.

In a past [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42770084/load-email-messages-attached-to-transaction-suitescript-2-0) there was a workaround for it using the search module. I can't seem to build another search to ascertain the info I want, so my real question is if there is a way outside of the search module to work with sublists that aren't listed in the record browser.

If there isn't, then I am looking to get all transactions of a given type for a customer. So all Sales Orders or all Invoices, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would retrieve this information using a Transaction search rather than a Customer search.

```js
// 1.0
function transactionsForCustomerByType(customerId, txType) {
    var filters = [
        ["mainline", "is", "T"], "and",
        ["type", "anyOf", txType], "and",
        ["entity", "anyOf", customerId]
    ];

    var columns = [ /* Your search columns */ ];

    return nlapiSearchRecord("transaction", null, filters, columns) || [];
}

var invoices = transactionsForCustomerByType(1234, "invoice");

// 2.0
// N/search imported as `s`
function transactionsForCustomerByType(customerId, txType) {
    var filters = [
        ["mainline", "is", "T"], "and",
        ["type", "anyOf", txType], "and",
        ["entity", "anyOf", customerId]
    ];

    var columns = [ /* Your search columns */ ];


    var search = s.create({
        "type": s.Type.TRANSACTION,
        "filters": filters,
        "columns": columns
    });

    return search.run().getRange({"start": 0, "end": 1000}) || [];
}

var invoices = transactionsForCustomerByType(1234, s.Type.INVOICE);
```

If a sublist or a record is not listed in the Record Browser, then it is likely not scriptable - at least not via any officially supported method.

Comment: Could you edit to also provide the 2.0 version to your answer (I can translate, but for future users)? @erictgrubaugh

Comment: Thanks for the help. I believe it should be `return search.run().getRange({ start: 0, end: 1 });` instead of `getResults`

Comment: is it possible to filter for multiple types in the same search. I am filtering on recordtype (string), and based on the documentation it seems like the ANY operator is what I am looking for. However, when I perform `["recordtype", search.Operator.ANY, ["type1", "type2"]]` I just receive a list of all transactions for that customer.

Comment: Not sure `ANY` will work here; I think you will need to do `["recordtype", IS, "type1"], 'OR', ["recordtype", IS, "type2"]]`

Comment: I did try to do this and two things happened. First, the runtime took more than a few minutes (usually a few seconds). Second, it returned just orders of type 1, but not type 2.